# How to calculate Instance hour in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

I have a personal project and I want to deploy it to GCP. I read doc in GCP but I still don't understand how instance hours are calculated. For example, Is there any differences between running instance 1 hour in F1 and running instance 0.5 hour 1 instance hour in F2. I read that the "instance-hours" shown on the bill, dashboards, refer to the F1 instance class, the smallest one

Comment: I just wanted to  understand your question. What is F1 and F2 means here? Are you want to use Google Compute Engine(VM)?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [official documentation about hourly pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/all-pricing), because it may differ from each zone and have a look as well as [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator).

It takes time to calculate the billing for a new VM so please expect a more accurate billing forecast 24h after the usage of a VM. If you wish to have a GCP pricing in real time you may see this [official blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/introducing-cloud-billing-catalog-api-gcp-pricing-in-real-time), but I believe it won't be useful for your scenario due to complexity and cost of implementation.

Which may  You also may find useful the view of [forecasted costs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#cost-forecast).

Answer (score 0):

If you read "F1" and "F2", you are reading in the App Engine documentation. You have [28H free per day of F instance class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Instances). Above the free tiers, the [standard prices are enforced](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#standard_instance_pricing).

In your billing, the cost is based on the type of instance (F or B) and multiplied by the type of instance.

> For example, if you use an F4 instance for one hour, you see "Frontend Instance" billing for four instance hours at the F1 rate.